# Change the DST in Manual Mode

Tags: php

because of a special case in my country, the date of changing DST is different with the rest of the world.

so I want to handle the dst in manual mode.

I've searched a lot, but I cannot find anything. How can I do it?

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: i tried to save a boolean value in my application which admin make it true if is DST